# NUnit3.0: OneTimeTearDown method is being called after executing first test class and doesn't go in other test classes in same namespace

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit, nunit-3.0

I'm working on Selenium with C# using NUnit3.0 test framework I have created one `BaseSetup` class which has `OneTimeSetup` and `OneTimeTearDown`.

I use this class as parent class in all my test classes and are experiencing a problem with the `OneTimeTearDown` method. The `OneTimeTearDown` method executes after execution of all test methods in my first test class and doesn't execute the test method of other test classes in same namespace.

Please suggest a solution that how to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Also asked and answered at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nunit-discuss/BHlItmdYwB4

Short answer: TestFixtures are not supposed to inherit from SetUpFixtures.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Charlie, I got the point from your comment made in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nunit-discuss/BHlItmdYwB4 link

For the further reference of readers I'm posting here that what I did to overcome this problem that I was facing.

**What I intended to do:** I created a SetUpFixture class and initialized the driver and other components that I wanted to use throughout my all test classes containing TestFixture. The method that I followed to achieve it was by inheriting the SetUpFixture class in my all test classes to use the same driver and other components so that I had no need to create and initialize it every time when I add  new test class

**Problem:** problem occurred when the OneTimeTearDown of SetUpFixture class started executing as soon as it finishes the test execution of any one test class but OneTimeSetup did not initialized the components again and control passed to second test class (which was also inheriting the SetUpFixture class) to execute the test methods inside it but as the test cleanup was already processed by OneTimeTearDown there was no instance of driver to run the test methods of second test class and thats where all test cases started failing.

**Solution:** To overcome this situation what I did
     1. I made the SetUpFixture class as an individual class and did not inherit it any other test classes
     2. To reuse the drivers and other initialized components in SetupFixture I choose another way. I created a local driver in each test classes and initialized that with the driver      created in SetUpFixure class.
     3. I have some encapsulated methods in my SetUpFixture class so to reuse those methods I started calling them by prefixing the SetUpFixture class name